# WCF allow methods to be called only from TCP connections

Tags: .net, wcf, net.tcp

I have a WCF service that has 2 bindings: a HTTPS binding transport with message credential, and a TCP binding, security none.
I use the TCP binding from a website that is hosted on the same machine to get private data.

Is there a way so that i make some methods from the WCF available only for the TCP connections and not the HTTPS connections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to create two seperate Interfaces. You can use one interface to specify the operations available for endpoint using the HTTPS binding and the other one for the TCP binding. Depending on your setup you can still use the same instance for the implementation.